# One Page Contact Form PHP & Script

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, overlay

I am making a one page website, and I would like to add a contact form in one section. So I am working with PHP, thing is, I cant seem to find any base pre-made forms that do not open a new webpage or direct that you to a new page once you submit. I would like to keep this one page, so I would like an overlay to appear once everything is all correct in the form and it has been submitted. No popups or redirects.  This may require jQuery but I am not sure how to put it in so it actually does that.

Here is how I have set up the form in HTML:

```
 <form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <label></label>
        <input name="name" required placeholder="Your Name">
        <label></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your Email">
        <label></label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>     
       <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

Here is mail.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Website'; 
$to = 'email@emailhere.com'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
echo '<p>Thank you for your message! </p>';
} else { 
echo '<p>An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; }}?>
```

Now, I would like to be able to remove the echo for the thank you message, and replace it with jQuery code for an overlay I made.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    });
```

I am missing a part of the function, as right now its just going to show when the page is ready. But I don't know where to put that/how it works with this PHP.

My confusion is I am not sure where the PHP is telling it to go to some blank page when you hit submit, so I don't know where to stop and start the script. I also just don't know how to mesh this all together properly. Is it in the PHP or the script where I have it check all elements before it can call to action the "thank you overlay". I just don't really know what direction to go from here.

Thank you so much for your time. I am learning a lot of this on my own so my knowledge is patchy.

Please let me know if I can help clear anything up.

-rj

Comment: remove <?php portion before  if ($_POST['submit']) {

Comment: @jewelhuq If you remove just that, it will create syntax errors...

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Usually, you throw data by the server by going to another page, so you do a "synchronous" request. The Ajax technique enables you to stay on the page, while a request is made, an "asynchronous" request. JQuery makes Ajax requests much simpler. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `onclick` event on `#submit` button and use a Javascript `XMLHttpRequest` object instead of `action="mail.php"` in the form

Answer (score 0):

This is working from example, hope it can push you on correct path :)

Add this string right after submit button

```
<span class="status"></span>
```

PHP

```
if($mail_sent){
  echo "<span class='notice'>Your message has been sent, thank you.</span>";
  exit;
}else{
  echo "<span class='error'>We couldn't send your message please try again, thank you.</span>";
  exit;
}
```

And JS part to display errors

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(){
        return false;
    })
  $("#contact-form input[type=submit]").click(function(event){
        var formerror = false;

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').css({'cursor': 'auto', 'opacity': 0.5});
        $('.status').fadeIn('normal').html('Loading please wait...');

        $(this).closest("form").find("input, textarea").each(function(){
            error = false;
            switch($(this).attr('id')){
                case 'name':
                    if($(this).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/) == null || $(this).val() == "Name")
                        error = true;
                    else
                        error = false;

                    break;

                case 'email': 
                    if($(this).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/) == null)
                        error = true;
                    else
                        error = false;

                    break;

                case 'message':
                    if($(this).val().length < 4 || $(this).val() == "Type your message")
                        error = true;
                    else
                        error = false;

                    break;
            }
            if(error){
                $(this).css('border-color', '#f00');
                formerror = true;
            }
        });

        if(formerror){
            $('.status').fadeOut('normal', 
                                function(){
                                    $(this).html("One or more required fields are missing or invalid, please correct and resend.")
                                             .addClass("error");
                                }
                            ).fadeIn();

            $(this).removeAttr('disabled').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'opacity': 1});

            event.preventDefault();
        }else{

            //get teh link
            $.post( "contact.php", { name: $('#name').val(), 
                                         email: $('#email').val(), 
                                         website: $('#website').val(), 
                                         message: $('#message').val() 
                                        })
            .done(function( data ) {
                $('.status').removeClass('error').fadeIn('normal', function(){$(this).html(data)});
                $("#contact-form input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled').css({'opacity': 1, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```